# What is a good pattern to share a custom dispatcher for Exposed in KTor With Koin

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin, kotlin-exposed

I've been a huge Kotlin fan for a long time, but generally have only used it as a Java-replacement, ie with traditional Java libraries & frameworks like Spring. I'm currently going down the rabbit hole of exploring "pure kotlin" solutions to everything. Part of that is doing a little practice project using KTor, Koin, and Exposed.

I love the non-blocking behavior of Kotlin Coroutines, but obviously Exposed using purely blocking APIs under the surface. Since database operations are limited by the size of the connection pool to begin with, this isn't the end of the world IMO.

To begin with, I've got a really nice, neat, and working solution where I'm performing all my Exposed operations using `Dispatchers.IO`. This allows coroutines to handle the requests in a non-blocking way, while also using Exposed.

```
fun Route.getAllPeople() {
  get("/people") {
    val list = newSuspendedTransaction(Dispatchers.IO) { Person.all().toList() }
    call.respond(list.map { PersonResponse(id = it.id.value, name = it.name, age = it.age) })
  }
}
```

The main thing I don't like about this is relying on the default IO dispatcher. It has 64 threads, which is more than enough for my needs, but I have this idea that the number of threads and number of connections in the connection pool for my database should be the same. Because of this, I want to use a custom dispatcher specifically for operations involving this datasource.

Configuring such a dispatcher is fairly easy, as shown below. I can also share the dispatcher as a Koin dependency:

```
fun Application.databaseKoin() {
  val config =
      HikariConfig().apply {
        jdbcUrl = environment.config.property("postgres.jdbcUrl").getString()
        username = environment.config.property("postgres.username").getString()
        password = environment.config.property("postgres.password").getString()
      }

  // I know this defaults to 10, but the point is I can customize the connection pool and therefore the dispatcher
  val postgresPool = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(config.maximumPoolSize)

  koin {
    val module = module {
      single<DataSource> { HikariDataSource(config) }
      single<CoroutineDispatcher>(named("postgresPool")) { postgresPool }
    }
    modules(module)
  }
}
```

The main limitation I'm running into with this approach is the need to explicitly inject the dispatcher anywhere I want to use it. This is an additional piece of overhead for my code that I do not personally like, as it results in needing to write something like this everywhere:

```
fun Route.getAllPeople() {
  val dispatcher by inject<CoroutineDispatcher>(named("postgresPool"))
  get("/people") {
    val list = newSuspendedTransaction(dispatcher) { Person.all().toList() }
    call.respond(list.map { PersonResponse(id = it.id.value, name = it.name, age = it.age) })
  }
}
```

Obviously this is not the end of the world, but I don't like it.

Now yes, there is no mandatory reason to do this instead of using `Dispatchers.IO`. This project is certainly simple enough that it's not a big deal, but the goal is to learn more about these tools and understand them well enough to leverage them in larger projects in the future.

I could just create my own suspended transaction function, the problem is I don't know how to access a Koin dependency within it:

```
suspend fun <T> mySuspendedTransaction(
  db: Database? = null,
  transactionIsolation: Int? = null,
  statement: suspend Transaction.() -> T
): T {
  val postgresPoolDispatcher = TODO("???")
  return newSuspendedTransaction(postgresPoolDispatcher, db, transactionIsolation, statement)
}
```

Or maybe there's some way to setup and share this dispatcher and tie it to my pool size without needing Koin?

I'm really seeking some guidance here. I know I'm going down a bit of a rabbit hole, but I'm trying to explore new ways of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty opinion-based. Also, I'm not very familiar with Exposed, so I apologize if I provide some misinformation, but:

1. I see you don't provide `db` to `mySuspendedTransaction()`, and you don't use any other kind of handle to your DB. Does that mean this function accesses a database handle stored globally? If so, I don't see a reason to not do the same with the dispatcher. And if in fact you inject the db handle, you can have a single object that holds both the db and dispatcher.
2. I'm not sure if your idea of limiting the parallelism is correct. Even if you limit the parallelism, that doesn't limit the number of coroutines running concurrently. For example:

```kotlin
val dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(8)
repeat(16) {
    launch {
        newSuspendedTransaction(dispatcher) {
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case 16 coroutines will all try to acquire a transaction/connection. This is because you limited parallelism and you rather wanted to limit the concurrency. You can do the latter using e.g. a semaphore:

```kotlin
val semaphore = Semaphore(8)
repeat(16) {
    launch { 
        semaphore.withPermit {
            newSuspendedTransaction {
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't solve your problem though as you still need to access the semaphore everywhere.

3. I'm not sure if you need to limit anything in the first place. Normally, we create thread pools of the same size as connection pools, because if we use more threads than connections then excessive threads would wait on getting connections, so it would be wasteful. In this case we start a transaction using a suspending function, so maybe it was already implemented in a way that it doesn't block waiting on a connection, but suspends. I would definitely test this first.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to leverage the Ktor docs ([Ktor Exposed](https://ktor.io/docs/interactive-website-add-persistence.html), [Exposed Pooling](https://ktor.io/docs/connection-pooling-caching.html)) and combine available solution to do something like this:

```
class DatabaseConnector(config: ApplicationConfig) {
    val connection: Database
    
    init {
        val datasource = HikariDataSource(HikariConfig().apply {
            jdbcUrl = config.property("url").getString()
            driverClassName = config.property("driver").getString()
            username = config.property("user").getString()
            password = config.property("password").getString()
            maximumPoolSize = config.property("pool.maximumSize").getString().toInt()
            minimumIdle = config.property("pool.minimumIdle").getString().toInt()
            isAutoCommit = false
            transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
            
            validate()
        })
        
        this.connection = Database.connect(datasource)
    }
    
    suspend fun <T> transaction(block: suspend () -> T): T =
        newSuspendedTransaction(Dispatchers.IO) { block() }
}
```

This is a class I use in my project. Then I inject it anywhere it needs to be (usually to a service) via Koin as a Single as you do, and just implement the transaction as follows:

```
class ExampleService {
    val database: DatabaseConnector by inject(DatabaseConnector::class.java)

    init {
        transaction(database.connection) {
            SchemaUtils.create(Examples)
        }
    }

    suspend fun read(id: Int): ExampleEntity? =
        database.transaction {
            ExampleEntity.findById(int)
        }
}
```

And then use these functions in routes as I see fit.

```
fun Route.exampleRouting() {
    val exampleService: ExampleService by inject(ExampleService::class.java)
    
    route("example") {
        get("{id}") {
            val id = call.parameters["id"]?.let { it.toIntOrNull() } 
                ?: throw IllegalArgumentExepction()
                
            exampleService.read(id)?.let {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, it)
            } ?: throw IllegalArgumentExepction()
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example I have boiled down from a much more complicated code (where I map the entity to a serializable data class etc.), so I hope there are no mistakes in it.

Anyways, **Dispatchers.IO** utilizes up to 64 threads by default, or the number of cores, should you have more than 64 cores. I don't want to make statements about optimal number of connections in a pool vs optimal number of threads used by *CoroutineContext*, as I don't fully understand the science behind coroutines and whatnot, but any resources that are not under active usage should be free, from what I have understood. I have *maximumPoolSize* set to 128, *minimumIdle* to 4 and I utilize **Dispatchers.IO**, as is shown in the docs, with default 64 threads, and I have not run into any problems, though I have not tested the app under more demanding conditions with hundreds of users.